# Angular2 Filter issue

Tags: angular

here's how I am using the filter:

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of contacts | isMember">
           <ion-label>{{contact.name}}</ion-label>

           {{contact.phoneNumber}}-{{contact.isMember}}
       </ion-item>
```

Filter definition below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'isMember'})
export class IsMemberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): any {

        if (value.isMember === true) {
            return value;
        }
        return undefined;

    }
}
```

Goal is to only display rows that have isMember flag set to true.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isMember' of undefined
```

Here's a plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fLdNAoMGLU8vkGOFmrV8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ensure your pipe doesn't explode when `null` is passed in as value. Also return all values at once. The pipe doesn't get called with each value but with all contacts at once:

```
@Pipe({name: 'isMember'})
export class IsMemberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, crit:boolean): any {
      console.log('x');
        console.log('log', value, crit);
        if (value) {
          return value.filter(v => v.isMember === crit) {
        } 

        return [];
    }
}
```